# Can't terminate TCL script using exit command as it is not being identified

Tags: tcl, quartus

Here is the error message:

```
May 10, 2021 4:01:35 PM com.altera.debug.core
SEVERE: java.lang.Exception: invalid command name "exit"
    while executing
"exit 
"
    invoked from within
"if {$use_specified_base_addresses == 1} {

    puts "using predefined peripheral base addresses"

    # Peripheral address offset from taken from ..."
```

It is strange that the keyword "exit" is not being identified by the interpreter I am using. I just need to stop running the script when "catch" actually catches error raised by a procedure call. I am getting this problem in Quartus Prime Standard System Console.

Comment: Thank you for saying “Quartus” in your question; that was _extremely_ useful in looking up relevant help.

Answer (score 1):

The `exit` command is a standard Tcl command, but it looks like it has been removed from the interpreter, presumably because it is being run in an environment which wants to keep on running. (Tcl definitely supports defining interpreters with restricted command sets.) You'll have to check the application documentation on what to use instead.

Poking around in what Google digs up, [the `qexit` command](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/tafs/tafs/tcl_pkg_misc_ver_1.0_cmd_qexit.htm) (if defined) might work instead. It's apparently called like this:

```
qexit -error
```

I've no idea why they don't follow the standard `exit` protocol.

Comment: You are correct about keeping the interpreter running part. I wonder when hardware design tools will be as good as software design tools.